# Windows 10 - Restrict Users access to cmd/powershell via a cmd command

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

I understand the method to restrict a user's access to cmd and/or powershell via the registry, however I'd like to know if there is a method to do this via cmd from an administrator account.

Comment: You can modify the registry from a command line but you would be just using a group policy to do so

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd as admin

Use takeown to take ownership over cmd.exe or powershell.exe
Read more:
takeown /?

When you (the admin) have ownership:
Use icacls to change user rights for a file
Read more
icacals /?

Comment: This approach can seriously break stuff. Some startup scripts that require cmd or powershell will stop working with the wrong permissions. A note of caution should be placed.